# Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService Authorization failing

Tags: asp.net, authentication, .net-core, jwt, amazon-cognito

I am trying to setup a simple Authentication setup for my api routes in my .NET 2.1 instance.

I am using this exact same methodology on my Nodejs backend and it works perfectly.

Currently I am getting the following errors when testing locally:

```js
Now listening on: http://localhost:50001
Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[1]
      Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://localhost:50001/api/test
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Route matched with {action = "Get", controller = "Test"}. Executing controller action with signature System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.String] Get() on controller EJ2FileManagerServices.Controllers.TestController (EJ2AmazonS3ASPCoreFileProvider).
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.DefaultAuthorizationService[2]
      Authorization failed.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[3]
      Authorization failed for the request at filter 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Authorization.AuthorizeFilter'.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ChallengeResult[1]
      Executing ChallengeResult with authentication schemes ().
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer.JwtBearerHandler[12]
      AuthenticationScheme: Bearer was challenged.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker[2]
      Executed action EJ2FileManagerServices.Controllers.TestController.Get (EJ2AmazonS3ASPCoreFileProvider) in 16.9604ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost[2]
      Request finished in 172.7868ms 401
```

When I take away my Auth code this results with a 200 status and a json object for the GET.

## Startup.cs

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using System.Net;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace EJ2FileManagerService
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.SaveToken = true;
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKeyResolver = (s, securityToken, identifier, parameters) =>
                        {
                            // Get JsonWebKeySet from AWS
                            var json = new WebClient().DownloadString(parameters.ValidIssuer + "/.well-known/jwks.json");
                            // Serialize the result
                            return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JsonWebKeySet>(json).Keys;
                        },
                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = $"https://cognito-idp.{Region}.amazonaws.com/{PoolId}",
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) => expires > DateTime.UtcNow,
                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = AppClientId,
                    };
                });
            services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
            services.AddCors(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", builder =>
                {
                    builder.AllowAnyOrigin()
                    .AllowAnyMethod()
                    .AllowAnyHeader();
                });
            });
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            // Auth Code
            app.UseAuthentication();
            // Auth Code
            app.UseMvc();

        }
    }
}
```

## Test Controller

```js
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;


namespace EJ2FileManagerServices.Controllers
{

    [Authorize]
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
        }

        // GET api/values/5
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
        public string Get(int id)
        {
            return "value";
        }

        // POST api/values
        [HttpPost]
        public void Post([FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // PUT api/values/5
        [HttpPut("{id}")]
        public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
        {
        }

        // DELETE api/values/5
        [HttpDelete("{id}")]
        public void Delete(int id)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Note I removed the values for the Cognito details. I am very new to using .NET so I am afraid the ordering may be an issue somewhere as I see that is a common problem with the error I am receiving. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure your issue about that but you can try add **"app.UseAuthorization();"** under to **"app.UseAuthentication();"**. Middleware order is so important in .Net Core by the way.